# Redirecting User to Folder Within Apache on Linux

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, redirection

I want the user to access http://www.xyz/internal/, then I need authentication and based on the user I will then send them to a subdirectory. So the scenario is, if user TOM goes to .../internal/ I want him having to log in and if the login is successful he is redirected to .../internal/tom/. Within that folder is a simple php script. If the user MIKE logs in I want him to redirect to .../internal/mike/

Answer (score 0):

A [rewriterule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) could be used to accomplish this.

Something like

```
RewriteCond  %{REMOTE_USER}  ^TOM
RewriteRule  ^/internal$                 /internal/tom  [L]
```

or more generally

```
RewriteCond  %{REMOTE_USER}  ^([A-Za-z]+)
RewriteRule  ^/internal$             /internal/$1 [L]
```